# How to hide uninformative part of errors in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I would like to hide debug-log with uninformative information in VS Code.

[image]

Comment: Did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In v3.4.0 of the Dart/Flutter extensions for VS Code, error messages should be improved:

https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-4/#improved-flutter-errors

[image]

If you see any bad errors/stack traces when using the latest version of Flutter and the VS Code extensions, please open issues on GitHub with examples. Thanks!